# Is it possible to call multiple methods or objects at once?

Tags: ruby, loops, object, methods, counter

Say I have a method that includes a counter that outputs it's count to the screen on every tick. 
Elsewhere in the program, a new version of this method is called, so they both/all run at once, have different counters, and update together with the tick. Is it possible to do this with Ruby? Normally creating another instance of an object is what I would do, I am still new to Ruby though and getting the hang of it.

I will edit with sample code of what I am trying to achieve later. I'm currently on a mobile without access to a computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I'm creating two instances of a `Counter`, both counters are initially set to 0. Then I launch them 3 seconds apart - each in its own thread. They start to print out numbers.

```
class Counter
  def initialize
    @counter = 0 # initial counter to 0
  end

  def run
    loop do
      # wait one second, print the counter and increase it
      sleep 1
      puts @counter
      @counter += 1
    end
  end
end

threads = []

2.times do
  # put each counter in a separate thread
  threads << Thread.new do
    counter = Counter.new
    counter.run
  end

  sleep 3 # make a pause between launching counters    
end

threads.each(&:join)
```

Output I get:

```
0 # first
1 # first
2 # first
0 # second
3 # first
1 # second
4 # first
2 # second
5 # first
```

The only trick here is to use `Thread` class, otherwise second counter will never start to work since the first counter will block the whole process.

Comment: This worked awesome! The way I was trying to implement it, I needed it to be continuously adding and subtracting from the objects and it was getting hectic. Believe it or not, I wound up using a 2d array and using shift/unshift to get the counters. It was the weirdest way to go about, but it seems to have worked. I will be remembering these for future reference though. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a queue and an external loop, something like:

```
class Counter

  def initialize(start)
    @count = start
  end

  def tick
    @count += 1
    puts @count
  end

end

queue = []
queue << Counter.new(0)
queue << Counter.new(100)

5.times do |i|
  puts "--- tick #{i} ---"
  queue.each(&:tick)
  sleep 1
end
```

Output:

```
--- tick 0 ---
1
101
--- tick 1 ---
2
102
--- tick 2 ---
3
103
--- tick 3 ---
4
104
--- tick 4 ---
5
105
```

Within the `5.times` loop, `tick` is sent to each item in the queue. Note that the methods are called in the order the counters were added to the queue, i.e. they are *not* called simultaneously.

Comment: I actually really like this method, and it is similar to what I wound up doing. I just worry about massive arrays in a bigger situation.

Comment: @Rockster160 the `queue` array just stores 2 `Counter` instances, not every tick.

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose you could use either Event loop, or Processes, or Threads. Because in common case Ruby will be blocked while method is executing (till it will return control with `return`).

```
class ThreadCounter
  def run
    @thread ||= Thread.new do
      i = 0
      while !@stop do
        puts i+=1
        sleep(1)
      end
      @stop = nil
    end
  end

  def stop
    @stop = true
    @thread && @thread.join
  end
end

counter1 = ThreadCounter.new
counter2 = ThreadCounter.new
counter1.run
counter2.run
# wait some time
counter1.stop
counter2.stop
```